# Using foreach to avoid redundant XPath form processing code

Tags: php, xml, xpath, foreach, attributes

Answered @ [setAttribute not saving back to XML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707620/setattribute-not-saving-back-to-xml-page/56758730?noredirect=1#comment100078199_56758730)

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facilities>
    <areas>
        <area name="Rocket">
            <trails>
                <trail name="Trail 1" status="CLOSED" />
                <trail name="Trail 2" status="CLOSED" />
                <trail name="Trail 2" status="CLOSED" />
            </trails>
        </area>
    </areas>
</facilities>
```

I am successfully able to edit the attributes using the following code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <?php
 $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $xml->formatOutput = true; 
 $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 $xml->load('example.xml');

 $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);

 $asstatus = $xpath->query("//facilities/areas/area[@name='Rocket']/trails/trail[@name='Trail 1']/@status")->item(0);

$childForm = '';
foreach ( $xpath->query("//trails/trail") as $trail )   {
  $childForm .= "<form action=''>
  <span class=\"title\">".$trail->getAttribute("name")."</span> <span class=\"title\">Status</span>
  <select name=\"asstatusform\" >
  <option selected value=".$trail->getAttribute("status").">".$trail->getAttribute("status")."</option>
  <option value=\"OPEN\">OPEN</option>
  <option value=\"CLOSED\">CLOSED</option>
  <option value=\"RACING CLOSURE\">RACING CLOSURE</option>
  </select></span>
  <br>
  </form>";
}

 ?>

 <form action="" method="POST">
    <?php echo $childForm; ?>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$trail->setAttribute('status', $_POST['asstatusform']);
htmlentities($xml->save('example.xml'));
 }

 ?>
```

What I'm wondering if there's an easy way to change it to use foreach so that I don't have to create a new query and form for each separate trail name. I've tried a few variations thus far, to no great success.

Answer (score 0):

A simple combination of using XPath to fetch the list of trails and then for each trail fetching the attributes for the display.

```
foreach ( $xpath->query("//trails/trail") as $trail )   {
    echo $trail->getAttribute("name")."/".
          $trail->getAttribute("status").PHP_EOL;
}
```

You can decide on how you want to display this data - separate forms/table etc.

The output in your code switches from echoing the data to HTML with embeded PHP.  You need to be consistent and ensure that it you also properly nest your quotes.  The following should work in the loop...

```
    echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=''>
  <span class=\"title\">".$trail->getAttribute("name")."</span> <span class=\"title\">Status</span>
  <select name=\"asstatusform\" >
  <option selected value=".$trail->getAttribute("status").">".$trail->getAttribute("status")."</option>
  <option value=\"OPEN\">OPEN</option>
  <option value=\"CLOSED\">CLOSED</option>
  <option value=\"RACING CLOSURE\">RACING CLOSURE</option>
  </select></span>
  <br>
  <input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\" />
  </form>";
```

Comment: Hey Nigel, thanks for the response. I am trying to display this by echoing the entire form inside the foreach statement and replacing <?php echo $asstatus->nodeValue  ?> with <?php echo $trail->getAttribute("name")  ?> but it just pops up with an internal server error. I still haven't figured out how I would then POST the attributes back either but one step at a time I guess. :)

Comment: OK - can you add the code to the question - and also add what and where the error is.

Comment: Edited to reflect, the error is just "internal server error 500"

Comment: Your code had various problems with unescaped quotes and mixed echo/php, I've changed it and posted it in the answer.

Comment: Nigel, thank-you. That works a charm. I've changed it so that the values are reflected inside a single submit button. I only have one more problem, which is with the post. Since it's no longer pulled by nodeValue, I can't use it to save the values. I've change the POST to use setAttribute instead, but now that shows a server error. $trail->setAttribute("status") = $_POST['asstatusform'];

Comment: I changed my syntax to ```$trail->setAttribute('status', $_POST['asstatusform']);``` and now the page loads but it doesn't update the values.

Comment: I figured out I can use my original code to change nodeValue by using getAttributeNode instead, but my problem is with item(). I think it's because I don't have an array defined.