# setAttribute not saving back to XML page

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I'm pulling data from and XML page and trying to write back to it with some PHP code. I have successfully done this by pulling the individual nodes with item(0) and `getAttributeNode`, then saving back to `nodeValue` instead of with `setAttribute`. My goal, however, is to make the code work with a `foreach` statement so that I don't have to go back in and edit it if trails are added and removed.

If I try to change it with `setAttribute` it doesn't work in either scenario (pulling them individually or with the `foreach` statement), and I can't figure out how to make the `getAttributeNode` and `nodeValue` work with a `foreach` statement. I think I may need an array but nothing I've tried has worked so far. I can get the page to load without an error but nothing happens when I click the submit button.

```php
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true; 
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('example.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);

$childForm = '';
foreach ( $xpath->query("//trails/trail") as $trail )   {
  $childForm .= "<form action=''>
  <span class=\"title\">".$trail->getAttribute("name")."</span> <span class=\"title\">Status</span>
  <select name=\"asstatusform\" >
  <option selected value=".$trail->getAttribute("status").">".$trail->getAttribute("status")."</option>
  <option value=\"OPEN\">OPEN</option>
  <option value=\"CLOSED\">CLOSED</option>
  <option value=\"RACING CLOSURE\">RACING CLOSURE</option>
  </select></span>
  <br>
  </form>";
}

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php echo $childForm; ?>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $trail->setAttribute('status', $_POST['asstatusform']);
  htmlentities($xml->save('example.xml'));
}

?>
```

Comment: If this is still an issue, can you provide a sample of what a `<trail>` element looks like?

Comment: ```<trail name="Trail1" status="CLOSED" difficulty="novice"/>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to edit this attribute "with a foreach statement" but you've got your `setAttribute` call outside the loop so you're only changing the last item. You're also nesting forms inside each other, which does not work.

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to individually update each of the trails' states, based on the form submission. To do that you'll need to submit an array back to the form and then loop through it. The potentially tricky part is matching the array with the the contents of the XML. Ideally you have some kind of unique identifier, but in this code I'm just assuming the order of the XML elements won't change between display and processing. So first POST entry is the first XML element, etc.

```
<?php
$xml    = new DOMDocument;
$xml    ->load('example.xml');
$xpath  = new DOMXpath($xml);
$trails = $xpath->query("//trails/trail");

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    foreach ($_POST["asstatusform"] as $k=>$state) {
        $trails->item($k)->setAttribute("status", $state);
    }
    $xml->save('example.xml');
}
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
<?php foreach ($trails as $trail): ?>
    <span class="title"><?= htmlspecialchars($trail->getAttribute("name")) ?></span>
    <span class="title">Status</span>
        <select name="asstatusform[]">
            <option selected value="<?= htmlspecialchars($trail->getAttribute("status")) ?>">
                <?= htmlspecialchars($trail->getAttribute("status")) ?>
            </option>
            <option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
            <option value="CLOSED">CLOSED</option>
            <option value="RACING CLOSURE">RACING CLOSURE</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Your inline HTML was giving me a headache, I can imagine you felt the same typing it out. Just break out of PHP for long blocks of HTML. I've used the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for the `foreach` loop, and [short echo tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) for output. Don't forget to always use [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to escape output to HTML pages.

Comment: Hey Miken - yes, you're correct in that the order doesn't change. I have this working with unique identifiers but the idea was that if I did it with the foreach I wouldn't have to create the same options/select/etc for the items individually. Thanks for the response - you've already taught me several things here. I'll try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: What I meant by unique ID was if your XML looked like `<trail id="2342" name="Trail1" status="CLOSED" difficulty="novice"/>` then you could use 2342 within your `foreach` loop to identify that element with 100% accuracy.

Comment: How would that work inside the loop? I could add an ID in - would they be incremental values?

Comment: They could be whatever you want. Then you name your form elements `asstatusform[<?=$trail->getAttribute("id")?>]` instead of just `asstatusform[]`. When you loop through `$_POST["asstatusform"]` then `$k` will be the ID and you can use it to more exactly match the XML element to be updated.

Comment: When you put `[]` at the end of a form input name, you're telling PHP to build an array, but it's just sequential based on order that it gets inputs from the browser. If you put a value in it like `[value]`, then the array will be indexed by those values.

Comment: Thank you - this is amazing and it works! I have one more question for you if you don't mind. Do you know how I would sort this foreach by attribute tag so that it would only pull ```difficulty="novice"``` for example?

Comment: The XPath query would look something like `//trails/trail[@difficulty='novice']`

Comment: For some reason I thought that would update the incorrect tags but it's actually fine!

Comment: Well in the code I've got, the same XPath query is used for the update and display so it should always line up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195540/discussion-between-eleytheria-and-miken32).